# mount host directory as write only in the docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am using `python` image for my application using `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose`.

I want to mount the python path inside the container `/usr/local/bin` to the directory in the host. For this, my `docker-compose` looks like

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - ./.virtualenv:/usr/local/bin
```

And the `.virtualenv` directory is empty in the host.
After running the `docker-compose` and executing `python command`

```
python myfile.py
```

It gives error

```
python: command not found
```

It is probably because it is syncing `.virtualenv` directory as the source.

How can I use the `.virtualenv` directory as `write-only` so that the contents of `/usr/local/bin` maps to this directory and does not copy from this directory to the container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I am right but try python3
if it does not work I really don't know

Answer (score 0):

Bind mounts *always* take a directory from the host and inject it into the container, hiding what was originally in the image; they do not work the other way, and you can't use them to expose an image's contents to the host system.

The approach you describe has the further problem that Python virtual environments aren't really that portable.  They are tied to a specific filesystem location and a specific Python interpreter.  If the virtual environment is in `/home/me/.virtualenv` in one context and `/usr/local/bin` in another, it won't work, and if the host and container Python aren't the exact same version and build, it won't work either.

In Docker, generally an image should be self-contained: it includes the language interpreter, any libraries you might happen to need, and the application code.  You don't need to inject these parts into a container with a bind mount, and the copy in the image will be separate from the development environment you have on your host.  Further, since a Docker image is already isolated from the host, you don't need a virtual environment in a Docker context.  A very typical Python-based Dockerfile would look like

```sh
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ./myfile.py
```

and you can `docker run` this image, or include it in a `docker-compose.yml` file, without any `volumes:` at all.

Comment: Actually, I want to map the python installed packages (interpreter) in the IDE. But since the packages are installed inside the container, I'm mapping the volume so that I could assign the IDE interpreter to that directory in the host.

Comment: Why not use your host virtual environment directly; why go through the additional indirection of running it in Docker?  (You might be able to `pip install -e .` your application in editable mode in the Dockerfile, and then use a bind mount to only inject your application code and not the library dependencies; but just doing development directly on the host will be much easier.)